# Converting HTML string to PHP array

Tags: php, domdocument

Assuming an HTML string like this:

```
$str = '<p>Hello World!</p><p style="text-align:center"><img src="foo.png" /><br /></p>';
```

It is possible to convert it into an array like this?

```
[0] => '<p>Hello World!</p>'
[1] => '<p style="text-align:center">'
[2] => '<img src="foo.png" />'
[3] => '<br />'
[4] => '</p>'
```

I tried using DOMDocument many different ways but the problem seems to always boil down to parenting. I need to traverse the HTML without regard for parent/child relationships.

Comment: hi again greener, is `str` formatted like that, you copy pasted ?

Comment: According to an earlier comment HTML is all one line.

Comment: @chris85 so,I don't see the point of pasting it like that...

Comment: Yea, I figured OP would update to actual format.

Comment: @greener you aren't helping us to help you. roger out.

Comment: @PedroLobito see updated string.

Comment: I'll post a DOMDocument solution asa I'm on my station, also, to not get downvoted, make sure you show some code you've already tried ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@olibiaz' Answer will do..

Just wanted to show another way of doing this using preg_split.

```
$str = '<p>Hello World!</p><p style="text-align:center"><img src="foo.png" /><br /></p>';
$flags = PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY;
$regex = '/(<[a-z0-9=\-:." ^\/]+\/>)|(<[^\/]+>[^<\/]+<\/[a-z0-9]+>)|(<[a-z0-9=\-:." ^\/]+>)/';
$parts = preg_split( $regex, $str, -1, $flags);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
array (size=5)
    0 => string '<p>Hello World!</p>' (length=19)
    1 => string '<p style="text-align:center">' (length=29)
    2 => string '<img src="foo.png" />' (length=21)
    3 => string '<br />' (length=6)
    4 => string '</p>' (length=4)
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to use a PHP DOM extension for this?
Alternatively, you could simple explode on newlines as follows:

```
var_dump(explode("\n", $html));
```

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>Hello World!</p>
    [1] => <p style="text-align:center">
    [2] =>   <img src="foo.png" />
    [3] =>   <br />
    [4] => </p>
)
```

Comment: the HTML string actually has no line breaks :/

Comment: @greener the string in your opening post looks like it has newlines though, is that literally what the string looks like?

Comment: no the string is one single line. I just posted it like that for clarity but evidently could have been better

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex in order to achieve that.

```
$input = '<p>Hello World!</p><p style="text-align:center"><img src="foo.png" /><br /></p>';
$regex = '/(<[a-z0-9=\-:." ^\/]+\/>)|(<[^\/]+>[^<\/]+<\/[a-z0-9]+>)|(<[a-z0-9=\-:." ^\/]+>)/';


$result = []; 
preg_match_all($regex, $input, $result);

$result = $result[0];
```

`$result` will look like

```
array(5) {
  [0] =>
  string(19) "<p>Hello World!</p>"
  [1] =>
  string(29) "<p style="text-align:center">"
  [2] =>
  string(21) "<img src="foo.png" />"
  [3] =>
  string(6) "<br />"
  [4] =>
  string(4) "</p>"
}
```

But two important thing:

- For sure this regex pattern can be **improved**, its more like an example.
- **Test it on different cases** since i made a test on your particular example input and it could failed on more complex structure. In this case adapt it to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

No regex solution:

```
$str = '<p>Hello World!</p><p style="text-align:center"><img src="foo.png" /><br /></p>';
$tags = explode( '|', str_replace('><', '>|<', $str));
print_r($tags);
```

---

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <p>Hello World!</p>
    [1] => <p style="text-align:center">
    [2] => <img src="foo.png" />
    [3] => <br />
    [4] => </p>
)
```

---

[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/s7pVAF)